# dojo/i18n putting the values for "root" in a spearate file (ex: root:true)

Tags: internationalization, dojo, translation

**Background:** Originally I have this for messages.js

```
define({
  root:{
    EXAMPLE:"Example for stackoverflow"
  },
  "pl":true,
  "ru":true
});
```

in a directory structure that looks like

```
nls
  pl
    messages.js
  ru
    messages.js
  messages.js (where the contents are the code shown above)
```

Very standard and has worked for a decade or more.

**The problem:** Our translation team wants us to change how we structure our files for compatibility for their translation tools so that the default keys are defined in a file under a directory called "root"

I want something like this under nls:

```
define({
  root:true,
  "pl":true,
  "ru":true
});
```

Where we no longer have the default key/string pairs.  The default key.string pairs now have to go under nls\root. It would look look like any other language file:

```
define({
   EXAMPLE:"Example for stackoverflow"
});
```

The required overall directory structure would look like this

```
nls
  pl
    messages.js
  root
    messages.js (that is the default version of the key/string pairs)
  ru
    messages.js
  messages.js (that only includes the "lang":true parts)
```

**Summary of the question** Can anything be done to move the default strings out of the root property in the original file and to put the contents of root into a new file under a directory called root? If so, what am I missing?

Things that did not work:

```
define({
  root:true,
  "pl":true,
  "ru":true
});
```

and

```
define({
  "root":true,
  "pl":true,
  "ru":true
});
```

In both cases I see the key is not found so we dump out the key by default (our way of handling missing resources).

I have read through a lot of dojo documentation and feel we are going against the standards by attempting this.

Comment: you are right. this goes out of standards. you can't do it

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a fallback to root? What is your fallback, english? What about keeping the root object there empty, and add additional file for your default/fallback language

```
define({
  root:{
    // nothing here
  },
  "en":true,
  "pl":true,
  "ru":true
});
```

Comment: I honestly want to leave things as they should be but forces outside my organization wanted mine to look like other products built on different technologies.  I convinced them to let me be but you do offer an interesting approach and thank you.